# How to start learning SEO

Tags: seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best ways to increase your site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-your-sites-position-in-google)

I'm a web developer (.NET) and a newbie to the SEO world!

Where and how to start ?

What are the steps to go from a newbie to be a more experienced SEO ?

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: @John- How come this is a duplicate ? .. the question is about google optimizing and I'm talking about SEO WORLD! (In general) and the standards a website should be met to be SEO friendly!

Answer (score 1):

There are hundreds of SEO website out there, but I'll admit it's sometimes hard to find the good ones. I like SEOmoz.com, the Unbounce blog, the Performable.com blog, and a few others.

This article provides a TON of good basic information for someone just getting started, with links to all the necessary resources.

http://www.seanogle.com/uncategorized/become-an-seo-freelancer

Comment: +1 That's a good start .. but I can't find good resources on how to make a website SEO friendly! .. excuse me if I wasn't clear at first but I'm really new to this and as a developer when SEO is mentioned the first thing to think about is how to make my website SEO friendly and the steps to follow in my design and code (like displaying the information as text not as images or flash) and some other similar tips and standards